# Cheerio NPM trying to obtain values for img src in nodeJS

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio

Image of current source:
[Here](http://prntscr.com/k4ri1y)

Current code:

```
let imageArr = []
$('.plink image').each(function(){
    let image = $(this).attr('src')
    imageArr.push(image)
})
console.log(imageArr)
```

Log nothing , why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't has tag `image`, it is `img`.

Use `.plink.image img` instead of `.plink image`.

```
const $ = cheerio.load(body, {
    xmlMode: true // to load noscript
})
let imageArr = []
$('.plink.image img').each(function(a, b) {
    let image = $(this).attr('src')
    if (image && !image.match(/white.jpg$/)) { // remove template image
        imageArr.push(image)
    }
})
console.log(imageArr)
```

Comment: Can you tell me url ?

Comment: And are you sure $ was loaded ?

Comment: Can you upload all your code, may be you load $ failed.
I try it and my console logged array with 24 element.

Comment: OMG, it is '.plink.image img' not '.plink image img'

Comment: I get undefined array sometimes, all elements are undefined

Comment: Yes, I will try it

Comment: Do you want use other module ?
Or you need same your code, just fix something ?

Comment: use same code just fix something, because other times I do this it work, but not this time

Comment: Try load $ with this code :  const $ = cheerio.load(body, {xmlMode: true})

Comment: it logs undefined and different src, this is not the one I was looking for because it includes the white.jpg

Comment: Use `data-cfsrc` not `src` and don't use  {xmlMode: true} .
I updated my answer.

Comment: lol, bro ur method logs white image, I said it isnt what i was looking for because it includes that

Comment: But you want 'nike-sb-sb-zoom-blazer-chukka-xt-ah3366-002-1.jpg' or 'white.jpg' ?

Comment: 'nike-sb-sb-zoom-blazer-chukka-xt-ah3366-002-1.jpg'

Comment: Sorry, now, I am understand you, I will fix it

Comment: Updated, just a trick, not real of browser do it, if you want know what is browser doing, you should read javascript of that page.
Sorry my english.

Comment: Also, can I ask why does it need to be in XML mode?

Comment: Because  I load it from noscript 
https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#loading
If you don't use it, cheerio will remove it (with option of htmlparser2).